# How to *Rotate* labels in a Seaborn PairGrid?

Tags: python, label, seaborn

The columns in my dataframe has long names, so when I make a pairplot, the labels overlaps one another. I would like to rotate my labels 90 degrees, so they don't collide. I tried looking up online and documentation, but could not find a solution. Here is something I wrote & the error message:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
g = sn.pairplot(df, kind="scatter")
g.set_xticklabels(g.get_xticklabels(), rotation=90)
g.set_yticklabels(g.get_yticklabels(), rotation=90)
```

```
AttributeError: 'PairGrid' object has no attribute 'set_xticklabels'
```

**How can I rotate labels (both x and y) in a Seaborn PairGrid?**

*Note: Sorry, my wifi can't upload the image for reference.*

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Thanks to William's answer, I now know what to look for to solve my problem!

Below is how I did it.

```
g = sn.pairplot(dfsub.sample(50), kind="scatter", hue=target)
for ax in g.axes.flatten():
    # rotate x axis labels
    ax.set_xlabel(ax.get_xlabel(), rotation = 90)
    # rotate y axis labels
    ax.set_ylabel(ax.get_ylabel(), rotation = 0)
    # set y labels alignment
    ax.yaxis.get_label().set_horizontalalignment('right')
```

Answer (score 4):

You can iterate over the axes directly using the `axes` member of the `PairGrid` object returned by `PairPlot`. Something like this

```py
for ax in g.axes.flatten():
    ax.tick_params(rotation = 90)
```

Should do the trick

Comment: Thanks @William! Iterating through g.axes.flatten() is exactly what I was looking for! I am actually working with labels not tick_params, so I edited to what I needed and added a new answer for this question.

Comment: @TechTana My mistake, your usage of `get_xticklabels()` and `get_yticklabels()` in the question made me think you wanted to rotate the tick labels not the axis labels - and `tick_params()` is another way to do that. I'm glad you got use out of `g.axes.flatten()`.

Answer (score 4):

Adding to @techtana's answer. If you set `cornor=True` while plotting pairplot, then you need to skip `ax`es of `NoneType`:

```
g = sns.pairplot(df, diag_kind='kde', corner=True)
for ax in g.axes.flatten():
    if ax:
        # rotate x axis labels
        ax.set_xlabel(ax.get_xlabel(), rotation = -30)
        # rotate y axis labels
        ax.set_ylabel(ax.get_ylabel(), rotation = 0)
        # set y labels alignment
        ax.yaxis.get_label().set_horizontalalignment('right')
```